# Strongly compact cardinal with bad covering properties

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

This is a continuation of the question [covering properties of strongly compact embedding](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/173263/covering-properties-of-strongly-compact-embedding).

Recall that a cardinal $\kappa$ is $\nu$-strongly compact cardinal if there is an elementary embedding $j:V\rightarrow M$, with critical point $\kappa$, $j(\kappa) > \nu$, such that $j^{\prime \prime} \nu \subset s$ where $|s|^M < j(\kappa)$.

**Question 1:** Is it consistent (relative to the existence of large cardinals, of course), that there is a $\nu$-strongly compact cardinal $\kappa$, $\nu > 2^{\kappa}$ regular, such that for some $j:V\rightarrow M$, (a $\nu$-strongly compact embedding elementary embedding with $crit(j)=\kappa$), $j^{\prime\prime} \nu$ cannot be covered by any set from $M$ with order-type $\nu$?

Assuming that the answer to the first question is positive, how far can we get? namely:

**Question 2:** With the same notations, how large can be the gap between the minimal $M$-cardinality of a set in $M$ that covers $j^{\prime\prime} \nu$ and $\nu$? Does there is any non trivial restriction on this $M$-cardinal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, and indeed the situation is not merely
consistent with strong compactness, but rather every strongly
compact cardinal has such embeddings with no small covers.

**Theorem.** Suppose that $\kappa$ is $\delta^+$-strongly compact,
where $\delta^{\lt\kappa}=\delta$. Then there is a
$\delta^+$-strong compactness embedding $j:V\to M$ such that there
is no $s\in M$ with $j''\delta^+\subset s$ and $|s|^M=\delta^+$.

Proof. Let $j_0:V\to M_0$ be any $\delta^+$-strong compactness
embedding. Let $s_0\in M_0$ be a cover, so that $j_0''\delta^+\subset
s_0$, and we may assume without loss of generality that
$|s_0|^{M_0}=\delta^+$, for if there is no such cover then we are
already done. Let $j_1:V\to M_1$ be any $\delta$-strong
compactness ultrapower. We may consider $h=j_1\upharpoonright
M_0$, so that $h:M_0\to M$ is an elementary embedding of $M_0$
into $M=j_1(M_0)=\bigcup_\alpha j_1(V_\alpha^{M_0})$. Note that we
do not necessarily have the measure for $j_1$ inside $M_0$, and so
this embedding $h$ is defined in $V$ rather than in $M_0$. Let
$j=h\circ j_0:V\to M$ be the composition elementary embedding.
(Although the argument here will not use it, in fact one can prove
that $j:V\to M$ is the ultrapower by the product measure
$\mu\times\nu$, where $j_0$ is the ultrapower by $\nu$ and $j_1$
is the ultrapower by $\mu$.)

I claim that $j$ is a $\delta^+$-strong compactness embedding. It
clearly has critical point $\kappa$. Define $s=j_0(s_0)$. It
follows easily that $j''\delta^+=h''j_0''\delta^+\subset
h''s_0\subset h(s_0)=s$, and so $s$ covers $j''\delta^+$. And
$|s|^M=h(|s|^{M_0})=h(\delta^+)$, which is less than
$h(j_0(\kappa))=j(\kappa)$.

Meanwhile, since $s_0$ has size $\delta^+$ in $M_0$, it follows
that $\sup j_0''\delta^+$ has cofinality $\delta^+$ in $M_0$. But
now the key point is that $j_1$ and hence $h$ is continuous at
ordinals of cofinality $\delta^+$. Thus, $h(\sup
j_0''\delta^+)=\sup h''j_0''\delta^+=\sup j''\delta^+$. Therefore,
any covering set of $j''\delta^+$ in $M$ must have size at least
the cofinality of this supremum, which is $h(\delta^+)$, which is
the same as $j_1(\delta^+)$, which is larger than $j_1(\kappa)$
which is significantly larger than $\delta^+$ in $M$.

So every cover of $j''\delta^+$ in $M$ has size much larger than
$\delta^+$. QED

Comment: Thank you. This is a very nice argument. I wonder - can we get a situation in which for every $\nu$-strongly compact embedding with critical point $\kappa$ there is no small cover?

Comment: That is a good question, and I'm not sure how to do it. Perhaps one can hope to arrange that the kinds of embeddings I am building here are the only strong compactness embeddings that there are. It sounds possible, but complicated to arrange.

Comment: I guess the construction works even in the case $\delta=\kappa$, which reduces the strength of the hypothesis to a $\kappa^+$-supercompact cardinal $\kappa$. The argument shows that if $\kappa$ is $2^\kappa$-supercompact, then there is a $\kappa^+$-strong compactness embedding with no small cover.

Comment: I improved the argument to show that every strongly compact cardinal has such embeddings with no small cover.

Comment: Why does $j_1 (\kappa ) > \delta^{+}$? I can see why it should be true when $j_1$ is supercompact, but I don't see why it's true with strongly compact embedding.

Comment: Since $j_1$ is a $\delta$-strong compactness embedding, we have $j_1(\kappa)>\delta$ and also the $\delta$-strong compactness cover property, which implies $j_1(\kappa)\geq\delta^+$ by covering. This is sufficient for the argument, since $j_1(\delta^+)>j_1(\kappa)\geq\delta^+$. But alternatively, we can assume without loss that $j_1(\kappa)>\delta^+$, simply by replacing $j_1$ with $j_1\circ j_1$, if necessary; so there are such embeddings with $j_1(\kappa)>\delta^+$. Or, we could extract $j_1$ as the $\delta$-strong compactness factor of $j_0$, which will have $j_1(\kappa)>\delta^+$.